# Selenium doesn't create a Chrome object

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.11

With this simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url="https://google.com")
```

pycharm doesn't show anything; it's like it's trying to create the class but it never does.

I've tried a lot of things like installing webdrivers, specifying filepaths, and changing chrome configs, but none of those things worked.[pycharm loading forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhpLr.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do? All that code will do is open a browser to google

Answer (score 0):

'PyCharm' won't show anything regardless - it just runs your script, which may or may not try to start the Chrome-driver. You need the driver to match your browser version, otherwise it will try to start and immediately shut down. Check here: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

You may see a box flashing briefly, or miss it altogether. Once you have the proper version of the driver downloaded, you may need to refer to it - for example, I keep it in a `bin` folder next to the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./bin/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url="https://google.com")
```

Comment: It worked,thank you so much I added the chromedriver into the scripts folder and it worked perfectly.Thank you .

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel the answer is sufficient, consider clicking the checkmark next to it, so that your question no longer appears unanswered, and the answer can help others as well.